# Возвращение значения данных функции (в т.ч. Ajax)

Tags: javascript

У меня есть асинхронная функция, которая запрашивает данные по Ajax и может быть вызвана далеко не 1 раз. Облегчив себе работу вынес все дело с запросом в отдельную функцию и написал `return data;` и... Получил `undefined`.

Функция простая, не буду здесь постить ее копию, сделал простой вариант для примера, что бы было на чем показывать:

```js
$("#loadmore").on('input', function() {

   var test;
   sendData(function(outputData) {
   
      test = outputData;
      
   });
   console.log(test);
   
});
function sendData(callback) {
   //код запроса ajax
   //...
   //успех
   
   success: function(data, xhr)
   {

      outputData = JSON.parse(data);
      callback(outputData); 
             
   }
}
```

Этот код не работает, но я могу работать с данными внутри коллбека, это я понял. Но есть ли возможность вынести данные из функции, примерно как в этом коде?

Comment: вроде в JS уже завезли async/await?

Comment: Просто берите да выносите как обычно, коллбек это самая обыкновенная функция, как и любая другая. Просто учитывайте, что коллбек может быть вызван *в абсолютно любой момент времени* (хоть прямо сейчас, хоть через год), и на момент выполнения `console.log(test)` коллбек, скорее всего, ещё не запускался и поэтому test ещё пустой.

Comment: @VladD Я посмотрел. Это из `strict`? Я пока приторможенный, пишу на старом...

Comment: @Telion это из Babel)

Comment: @andreymal дак в этом и проблема! Как обычно не работает, получается неопределенное значение. Сколько инпутов не проходит и колбеков не тригерится все незаданные.

Comment: @Telion замените console.log на `setInterval(function(){console.log(test);}, 100);` и вы увидите, что всё работает ровно так, как я рассказал.

Comment: @Telion и вообще — что вам мешает работать с данными внутри коллбека? Именно так все и делают.

Comment: @andreymal Хм.. Да, работает, это я понял. Но в js нет никаких встроенных возможностей сделать то же без задержки? (в плане работать через setInterval это извращение).

Comment: @VladD, _вроде в JS уже завезли async/await?_ - в последней спецификации уже есть официально, хром точно поддерживает, но какие еще браузеры поддерживают - не знаю

Comment: @Telion ну, вообще в принципе есть, но от этого страница зависает нахрен и поэтому никто никогда так не делает, все просто обрабатывают данные в коллбеках и не парятся

Comment: @Grundy Если верить мозилле то ECMAScript 2017 Draft (ECMA-262) поддерживается уже всеми последними браузерами не включая IE и Edge.

Comment: @andreymal Окей, посмотрю что можно сделать. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: @Telion, тогда смотри пример использования в дубликате :)